# QDialog not centered on parent

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qdialog

I know that QDialog's are supposed to default to being positioned centered on the parent window but I'm apparently missing some subtlety. I have an object, derived from QWidget, and am trying to create a child dialog centered on that using the following test code

```
QDialog *dialog = new QDialog(this);
QPoint dialogPos = dialog->mapToGlobal(dialog->pos());
QPoint thisPos = mapToGlobal(this->pos());
dialog->exec();
```

When I do this, the dialog is showing up in the top left corner of my window. dialogPos is (0,0) and thisPos is (808, 371).

What am I missing? Why is the dialog not showing up centered as I would expect?

Comment: Have you tried to do something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18302990/867349 ?

Comment: That is for QWidget. My understanding is that for QDialog it should be done automatically.

Answer (score 7):

How to center QDialog to it`s parent QWidget

```
void Dialog::showEvent( QShowEvent* )
{
    QRect parentRect( parentWidget()->mapToGlobal( QPoint( 0, 0 ) ), 
parentWidget()->size() );
    move( QStyle::alignedRect( Qt::LeftToRight, Qt::AlignCenter, size(), 
parentRect ).topLeft() );
}
```

Comment: @ChandaKorat, this code is simple enough to be understood by the users of the Qt library. Actually, it's a benefit of using a high-level language in the first place - if properly written, a code should be self-explanatory. Furthermore, this one works perfectly and deserves to be accepted as a solution, instead of being downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

I subclassed a QDialog and put the following code in the constructor.

```cpp
QPoint dialogCenter = mapToGlobal(rect().center());
QPoint parentWindowCenter = parent->window()->mapToGlobal(
    parent->window()->rect().center());
move(parentWindowCenter - dialogCenter);
```

After that the dialog was centered over the parent window. My system is running Qt5.3.1 and Ubuntu 14.04.