# QDialog wrong positioning

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

We've got a dialog that is used as the main window. It is derived from `QDialog`. It has a fixed size and it is a full screen window.

```
// The form is a member variable.
form = new MyMainWindow( nullptr, Qt::Window | Qt::FramelessWindowHint );
```

After We've got this the user can access some tools menu which will pop up another dialog. I pass the `form` as the parent for this new dialog.

```
MyDialog dialog( /*Other parameters*/ this ); // Called from MyMainWindow.
dialog.setWindowIcon( QIcon( "MyIcon" ) );
dialog.resize( 1300, 1100 );
dialog.exec();
```

In the constructor of the `MyDialog` class I pass the parent widget to the base class.

```
MyDialog::MyDialog( /**/ QWidget* aParent )
: QDialog( aParent, 0 )
{
}
```

However sometimes the dialog is NOT centered over the main window. What could be the problem ?

We use Windows 7, Visual Studio 2012, Qt 5.4.0.

Comment: But **should** the child dialog appear in the center of its parent widget?

Comment: Could you explain *sometimes* a little bit? Is there a pattern you notice? Does the dialog pop up centered to the parent at first but not the 2nd time? Or is it just seemingly random? When it is not centered, at what position does it appear?

Comment: It should NOT be centered. You need to set position manually for top-level widgets.

Comment: I found one thing. We've got a dialog for demo purposes, and when it is available then the positioning is wrong. But when it is closed the positioning is better. But I think it's still not perfect, because the top and bottom margins are not the same.

Comment: Why should I position it manually ? If I create a `QDialog` and pass a parent `QWidget` to then the dialog shall be centered over the widget, or not (@SaZ) ?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose 'left', 'right', 'width', 'height' all belong to your dialog. This will position the widget and resize at the same time:

```
dialog.setGeometry( top, left, width, height );
```

Suppose 'this' points to the dialog or you can use the other pointer to that dialog. As long as you say your main window is widget (you pass it to the dialog as parent) takes the full screen, if you want to try to position the dialog within the parent:

```
QRect r = qobject_cast<QWidget*>(this->parent())->geometry();
this->setGeometry(
   (r.width() - width) / 2, (r.height() - height) / 2
   width, height);
```

P.S. I typed that in and did not try to compile but similar works for me.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not help something is wrong with the y-coordinate. In the meantime I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18302025/derrived-widget-not-centered-on-parent-when-shown-as-dialog), but it is not good neither.